# ios CoreData relationship with attribute

Tags: ios, core-data

I was wondering how to implement a relationship with an attribute using `CoreData`. `XCode 5` with `iOS 7`.

In my ER model I've got a relationship "participation" with the attribute "confirmed".

In this case I'd like to know whether participation in an event of a specific profile has been confirmed.

In `SQL` the table for this relation would look like this:

```
Participation (EventID, ProfileID, confirmed)
```

Unfortunately I can't post images due to lack of reputation.

Thanks in advance!

Nelson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new entity (`Participation`) which has 2 relationships (one to the `Event` and one to the `Profile`) and 1 attribute (your BOOL).

It isn't clear whether you already have this or not, but it can be used (by creating an instance of the entity) to connect your selected objects and hold the `confirmed` status.

Comment: You mean, i should use an intermediate entity as mention in figure 3 : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW9 ?

Comment: Yes, because you need additional information that isn't actually part of either of your existing entities.